# how can I query sum across columns, but avoid duplicated submissions / rows from unique users?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google form accepting data from different users, which goes to a sheet and is used to SUM the values across columns at the end of the day. The problem is that users can re-submit forms to update the data totals if there is a change at the end of the day:

```
    NAME    K   L   M
    ALF     4   0   1
    BILL    1   0   0
    SALLY   1   0   1
    DENNIS  1   1   1
    RICK    0   0   1
    SALLY   2   1   1  <--- SALLY RESUBMITTED HER FORM AGAIN WITH UPDATED VALUES
```

In my current Query, I SUM() the columns after filtering by the date like this:

```
SELECT SUM(K), SUM(M), SUM(N) WHERE C = date '"&TEXT($B$1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&
```

$B$1 is a cell with a datepicker and col C is the user submitted form date. Col A has the unique form generated submission timestamps

As you can see, the SUM for each column will be off by the extra submission from Sally. I need to include only the most recent submissions from any of the users, and ignore any prior ones for this date. I'm not sure how to filter in this manner and sum just the most recent instance from each unique user.

** EDIT **
I should note the original form data is on another sheet and the cells are referenced via a query to this range. The form is also submitted daily, so the query must be able to specify the date in question for summation of entries.

Comment: Use `Group by` and `Order By` clause. Share sample same as in your sheet.

Comment: Sure - here is a sheet with the sample data and my query: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V8VH29T6LAJhYpo7Dr08R8BdFh6zHUfZJlfD13Z5cpw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: See my answer and feedback your response to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try on following formula-

```
=QUERY(INDEX(REDUCE({0,0,0,0},UNIQUE(J2:J7),LAMBDA(a,b,{a;SORTN(FILTER(J2:M7,J2:J7=b,C2:C7=date(2023,2,17)),1)})))," select sum(Col2), sum(Col3), sum(Col4)")
```

If you actually want most recent response to sum then use-

```
=QUERY(INDEX(REDUCE(SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(A2:M7),0,0),UNIQUE(J2:J7),LAMBDA(a,b,{a;QUERY(SORT(FILTER(A2:M7,J2:J7=b),1,0),"limit 1")}))),"select sum(Col11), sum(Col12), sum(Col13)")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. In my real usecase, the datatable lives on another worksheet name 'data inputs'. Can this solution be used if the data is being referenced on another sheet?

Comment: Yes, just use sheet name Infront of ranges like `Sheet2!A2:M7`.

Comment: Thanks, the second query seems to work, except I need to also be able to specify the date of interest. Since the spreadsheet collects inputs each day, I need to specify the date for the submissions, and then get only the most recent submission within that date for each user. Is it possible to add this filter to the query?

Comment: @user1837608 Yes, possible. Actually you no need to specify date because second formula will always automatically pull most recent response of each person. If you want to add date criteria then could try- `=QUERY(INDEX(REDUCE(SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(A2:M7),0,0),UNIQUE(J2:J7),LAMBDA(a,b,{a;QUERY(SORT(FILTER(A2:M7,J2:J7=b,C2:C7=date(2023,2,17)),1,0),"limit 1")}))),"select sum(Col11), sum(Col12), sum(Col13)")
`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked as needed. I really appreciate you help here.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have another option, creating an auxiliary column that returns 1 if it corresponds to the date and is the last timestamp

```
=QUERY({K:M,
MAP(A:A,C:C,J:J,LAMBDA(ts,date,n,IF(date<>B1,0,IF(ts=MAX(FILTER(A:A,J:J=n,C:C=date)),1,0))))},
"SELECT SUM(Col1),SUM(Col2),SUM(Col3) where Col4=1")
```

[image]